# Handle NavigationCommands.BrowseBack Manually In A WPF Frame

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a frame in a WPF window.  If I click a back button on a page I can easily make some checks and call Frame.GoBack(). However if I click backspace or a special back key on a keyboard or remote then the Frame intercepts this call before it bubbles up to the main window and thus my code doesn't run.

Is there a way to stop a wpf frame from listening to NavigationCommands.BrowseBack?

Comment: did you try to handle PreviewKeyDown and set arg.Cancel = true in case of back button?

Comment: I can do an arg.handled = true but that would just stop any key event being handled by anyone. I want the parent of the frame to handle the event and not the frame.

Comment: could you handle it for frame only, and filter only back button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem by doubling up the CommandBindings. I now have the event being handled by the Window AND by the Frame.  Adding the CommandBinding to the frame appears to have overridden whatever the frame was doing natively.

```xml
<Frame x:Name="MainFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Focusable="False">
    <Frame.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="NavigationCommands.BrowseBack" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed_BrowseBack"/>
    </Frame.CommandBindings>
</Frame>
```